# Trouble using Silex framework on IIS

Tags: symfony, iis, iis-7.5, silex

I am trying to configure the silex framework and just get an example application working. I am using an IIS server version 7.5 to do so. On the following [website](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html) it gives me a sample web.config file I should be using. The file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Silex Front Controller" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is when trying to navigate to the website I just get the error:

> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.

So essentially IIS says the file is incorrect but I don't have much experience with these files so I don't know if there is a problem. Maybe the file is outdated and the newer doesn't work with newer versions of IIS. There is nothing in the server logs. Anyone come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to install the rewrite module for IIS at the following link:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module